# How to loop through array and ignore selected value

Tags: java, android

```
String response = "[\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"id\": 1,\n" +
        "    \"name\": \"What is your your father name\"\n" +
        "  },\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"id\": 2,\n" +
        "    \"name\": \"What is your mother's father name\"\n" +
        "  },\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"id\": 3,\n" +
        "    \"name\": \"What is your brother's father name\"\n" +
        "  },\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"id\": 4,\n" +
        "    \"name\": \"What is your father's father name\"\n" +
        "  },\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"id\": 5,\n" +
        "    \"name\": \"What is your sister's father name\"\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "]";
```

I have this set of questions and I wanted to loop through it to show in Dialog list. There are going to be 2 AlertDialog and if user select the value from one of the AlertDialog. The questions wont show in the other AlerDialog. For the loops, this is my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.q1:
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    if (selected2>-1)
                        q1 = new String[jsonArray.length()-1];
                    else
                        q1 = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                    int index = 0;

                    for (int x = 0; x<jsonArray.length(); x++){
                        idQuestion[index] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x).getInt("id");
                        if (selected2==x)
                            continue;
                        q1[index]= jsonArray.getJSONObject(x).getString("name");
                        index++;
                    }

                    AlertDialog alertDialog =new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                            .setTitle(R.string.select_security_question)
                            .setItems(q1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    question1.setText(q1[which]);
                                    if(selected == -1) {
                                        selected = which;
                                    } else {
                                        selected = which+1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }).create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.q2:
                try {
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(response);
                    if (selected>-1)
                        q2 = new String[ja.length()-1];
                    else
                        q2 = new String[ja.length()];
                    int index = 0;
                    for (int x = 0; x<ja.length(); x++){
                        if (selected==x)
                            continue;
                        q2[index] = ja.getJSONObject(x).getString("name");
                        index++;
                    }
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                            .setTitle(R.string.select_security_question)
                            .setItems(q2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    question2.setText(q2[which]);
                                    selected2 = which;
                                    if(selected2 == -1) {
                                        selected2 = which;
                                    } else {
                                        selected2 = which+1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }).create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
```

But I found that this logic is wrong.Questions are form server, that's why its is JSON format. If possible I want to use the id of the questions., since I'll have to return the value of id, not the question.

Comment: I don't understand make it more brief what you want buddy.

Comment: @ArpitPatel here, the user is required to select 2 questions from the same set of question. So I use 2 AlertDialog List  when user click the button and select the question. When user already selected one question, the same question shouldn't appear if user click on second button.

Comment: you are making things very complicated here...

Comment: @ArpitPatel also the questions actually come with id number, but I am not sure how to get the id into AlertDialog.setItems. So if there's any possible way for me to bring the id and the questions into the AlertDialog list without showing the  id.

Comment: @MichaelShrestha actually yeah I do realise I am making things complicated. But the more I try to get the logic right, the more lost I am

Comment: Just use ArrayList and make it simple in that you can add item and also remove item .

Comment: @ArpitPatel the set of questions are from server actually, its in JSON format. I am sorry for not stating it up there. Will update my question.

Comment: Ya but you can get that json value in ArrayList because it is easy to use

Comment: @ArpitPatel ohhh.. crap, why I never thought of that.. thanks for the idea!!

Comment: yes now you get it. You can simply add that questions using loop in that ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore values inside a loop use `if(id==id_ignored) continue;`

Comment: Actually the android questions part is there too. I want to bring the id into the AlerDialog.list as part of the value but not showing to user since it is id.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the complete solution but I am giving some idea on how to achieve it.

at first convert your all questions to `ArrayList` for that you can do manually or you can use `gson` as well.

```
public Question
{
  int id;
  String name;
}
```

First create a list of all questions
i.e. `ArrayList<Question> all`

then create another list for `ArrayList<Question> filteredList`

and store selected id in variables `selected_1, selected_2`;

as you select items you put assign it to `selected_1 or selected_2`
and filter items and put in `filteredList`

```
for (Question q : all)
{
 if (id in selected_1 or selected_2) //based on your alertdialog
    ignore;
else
  filteredList.add(q);
}
```

Use this everytime you select something

and to show the list in `AlertDialog` use this `filteredList`.